# XSS in URI in page without any input

Tags: php, security, xss

Is the XSS attack made by user input? 
I have recived attacks like this:

```
'"--></style></script><script>alert(0x002357)</script>
```

when scanning a php page without any html content with acunetix or netsparker.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remember that even if you had just a static collection of HTML files without any server-side or or client-side scripting whatsoever, you may still store you logs in an SQL database or watch them as HTML using some log analyzer which may be vulnerable to this kind of URIs. I have seen URIs in logs that were using escape sequences to run malicious command in command line terminals – google for escape sequence injection and you may be surprised how popular they are. Attacking web-based log analyzing tools is even more common – google for log injection. I am not saying that this particular attack was targeted at your logs but I'm just saying that not displaying any user input on your web pages doesn't mean that you are safe from malicious payloads in your URIs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. If I understood you correctly, you used a security scanner to check your web application for XSS vulnerabilities and it did show a problem about which you aren't sure if it really is a problem.

XSS is pretty simple: whenever there is a way to force an application to display unfiltered code a user provided, there is a vulnerability.

The attack code you show above seems to target a style tag that add certain user provided data (eg. a template variable or something similar). You should check if there's such a thing in your app and make sure it's properly filtered.

Comment: I have a simple index.php without any html in it. There is no any user input or html. But still I have security alert for URI XSS

Answer (score 0):

Blackbox scanners will try this attack even when your html doesn't expect any parameter because there is no easy way for them to know what's going on in your source code), if you don't echo anything or use stuff like `PHP_SELF` you are fine.

Also take a look at [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) to understand how XSS might happen without any server-side flaw.

If the scanner reports a vulnerability take a look at the description and source code, generally it will hilight the vulnerable part of the source code so you can see.

Secondly you can manually test and if executes JS then you can investigate whether it's about your framework, or a vulnerability in the javascript code or in URL Rewrite (maybe you echo your current path in the page) or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Where did you find this XSS?  As far as I am aware if a page does not take any user-input (a process/display it) it cannot be vulnerable to XSS.

**Edit:**

I think I misunderstood your question - did you mean can XSS occur by entering Javascript in the address bar in the browser?  Or by appending Javascript to the URI?  If the latter - then the page is susceptible to XSS and you should use a whitelist for any variables passed to your URI.  If the former, then no, any client-side changes in the address bar will only be visible to that single user.

Comment: Yes I mean javascript in url, but what is the solution for all javascripts? I have read many articles and test many serverside ways but yet I have alerts from scanners. Thanks for help

Comment: If you take any user input and display it unfiltered, you are susceptible to XSS.  If you do not take any you aren't.  Does your index.php take any $_GET variables?  If so, make sure they are checked against a whitelist and any other ones get disregarded